# $http request and ng-repeat loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently playing around with Angularjs and create a simple app to check domain availability. The scenario is: when user entering search query and submit the form, it will request a list of domains in JSON format, then loop the result using ng-repeat and check the availability one by one but it always give me an errors that refer to https://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D

The problem is triggered by **checkAvailability**, trying to figure it my self for hours but still couldn't find the solution. Hope someone here could help me.

Here is my controller:

```
app.controller('main', ['$scope', '$http',
    function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.searchResults = null;

        $scope.search = function () {
            $http.get('/api/domain/search?q=' + this.query).success(function (data) {
                $scope.searchResults = data;
            });
        };

        $scope.checkAvailability = function (domain) {
            // return true;
            $http.get('/api/domain/check?domain=' + domain).success(function (data) {
                return data;
            });
        };

    }
]);
```

example API response

```
#http://localhost/api/domain/search

[
    {
        "domain":"exampledomain1.com",
        "tld":"com"
    },
    {
        "domain":"exampledomain2.com",
        "tld":"com"
    },
    {
        "domain":"exampledomain3.com",
        "tld":"com"
    },
    {
        "domain":"exampledomain4.com",
        "tld":"com"
    }
]

#http://localhost/api/domain/check

"available" or "unavailable"
```

and here is my HTML

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="main">
    <form class="domain-search form mb40" ng-submit="search()">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" ng-model="query" class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search">
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>

    <ul ng-if="searchResults">
        <li ng-repeat="item in searchResults">{{ item.domain }} is {{ checkAvailability(item.domain) }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, this isn't going to work as architected. `checkAvailability` is a function that always returns undefined. Sure, you make a $http request in there, but you don't return anything. Even if you tried to return something, it'd only be the $http promise, as it hasn't returned yet (async).

I'd deal with all the data fetches together. Note it'd be better to do all this on the backend and surface one call. All these extra ajax calls to get each domain are wasteful.

```
app.controller('main', ['$scope', '$http', '$q',
    function ($scope, $http, $q) {

        $scope.searchResults = null;

        $scope.search = function () {
            $http.get('/api/domain/search?q=' + this.query).success(function (searchResponse) {
                var promises = [];
                for (var i = searchResponse.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    (function(i){
                        promises.push($http.get('/api/domain/check?domain=' + searchResponse[i].domain)
                            .then(function(domainResponse){
                                searchResponse[i].availabilty = domainResponse.data;
                            }, function(){console.error(searchResponse[i].domain)}));

                    })(i)

                };

                $q.all(promises).then(function(){
                    $scope.searchResults = searchResponse;

                })

            });
        };
    }
]);
```

--

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="main">
<form class="domain-search form mb40" ng-submit="search()">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" ng-model="query" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search">
        </span>
    </div>
</form>

<ul ng-if="searchResults">
    <li ng-repeat="item in searchResults">{{ item.domain }} is {{ item.availability }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how if there is a hundreds of domains, wouldn't it just increase a page load? Actually I'm inspired by iwantmyname.com domain search, as you can see it checks the results one by one.

Comment: Hey, looks like your code works if I move `$q.all(promises)..` to the top of `for` loop... thanks mate!

Comment: I imagine if you move `$q.all` above, it makes it so that the items load instantly, but the availabilities show up sporadically as they come in? It's fine, it just would be a little weird looking I'd think. If you want to do it that way, just take out the `$q.all` and `$scope.searchResults = searchResponse;` directly.

Comment: As to page load, it would increase load time. Which is why doing all this reconciliation of item domains and availability server side makes more sense.

Comment: Do you know how to make `for` loop continue to check the next item if previous process has been processed? as currently I getting internal error for few of them.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? The for loop kicks off a bunch of independent iifes, each one of which kicks of an `$http` request. The response of one should not affect the response of another.

Comment: I just did a minor edit, I forgot to pass a second function to .then, which is needed for error handling. Maybe that was the issue?

Comment: I think your code was fine, the problem is my api is using others api that only allows one request in one second for the same ip..

Comment: Still the same, does javascript or angular has a `sleep` function just like on php?

Comment: javascript has `setTimeout`. If you wanted, you could, in the for loop, do `setTimeout(function(){/*All the code for $http request */}, i*1000)`, which would delay each loop's execution by 1 seconds * the index. Alternatively, make it recursive and only kick off a request after the last one completed. Thats the only way to make sure only request happens at once. All very hacky, much better to handle this server side.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Dylan! I think do a hack in server side would be better, perhaps add more api source or using whois database instead. Thank you!